# SafeConfigParser shows up in Python Fabric's available commands

Tags: python, fabric

I am learning Python and playing around with the Fabric library. I learned that if you use `fab --list` command, it shows you the list of available commands.

```
from fabric.api import *
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import os

def install_nova():
    ...

def deploy_vms():
    ...
```

where `...` represents the code to be executed for the given command. When I do `fab --list` it should be only showing me the options `install_nova` and `deploy_vms`. However, I am getting this -

```
Available commands:

    SafeConfigParser
    deploy_vms
    install_nova
```

I have following questions -

- Why is `SafeConfigParser` appearing as an available commands?
- How can I get rid of `SafeConfigParser` from the available commands option?

Fabric version is :

```
Fabric 1.8.0

Paramiko 1.11.2
```

And python version is :

```
Python 2.7.5
```

Comment: Try `from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as _ConfigParser`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian this works too! Can you please explain why?

Comment: see [defining task section in the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/tasks.html#defining-tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply `@task` decorator to all you functions:

```
@task
def install_nova():
    ...
@task
def deploy_vms():
    ...
```

If you don't use `@task`, fabric will treats all functions as commands.

Comment: This works! However, if Fabric was treating all functions as commands, it shouldn't have shown SafeConfigParser, because I haven't defined any method with that name. I only have `install_nova()` and `deploy_vms()`.

Comment: Yeah, but you imported SafeConfigParser in your namespace.